# How to run application from docker container from host OS?

Tags: docker

I'm using docker container with ubuntu:14.04 and some C++ application that I compiled inside docker container.

Is it possible to run application that is inside container from host OS(in my case Win 7)?

Something like:

`docker run <path-to-binary>/mybinary -f 10 -o output.txt`

**UPDATE:**

Yes, it's possible

`docker run -it <my-image> <path-to-binary>/mybinary`

So ideally I want application inside docker will be just like native applications on Windows host OS.

Also is it possible to specify files and folder in host OS as input arguments to application that docker container can't see?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to mount shared folder at container start

`docker run -v C:\shared_with_VM:/temp my_image`

and also

`docker run -v "C:\shared_with_VM":/temp my_image`

But I get error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Invalid
bind mount spec "C:\\shared_with_VM:/temp": invalid mode: /temp.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

As said [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) right path format on Windows should be

`docker run -v /c/shared_with_VM:/temp my_image`

Comment: Try this syntax in Windows: `docker run -v //c/Users/mrgloom/Desktop/data:/data <image>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I correctly understand your question...

You can [mount folders](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) from your host to the container to make it accessible from within your container:

```
docker run -v /host/folder:/container/ -it <image> <executable> <arguments>
```

For example:

```
docker run -v /tmp:/tmphost -it ubuntu ls -al /tmphost
# or in Windows
docker run -v //c/Users/mrgloom/Desktop/data:/tmphost -it ubuntu ls -al /tmphost
```

This creates the folder `/container/` in your container and links it with `/host/folder`. You can then bidirectonally read / write files inside these folders. Your binary has to point to the input file, which might be located in `/container/input.txt`

Comment: Yes, you understand my question right, but seems command that you specify is wrong `-v` option will be related to `mybinary`? maybe order should be different?

Comment: I added another example which might make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, I understand your example, but seems you are using linux paths? See my update.

Comment: Seem by that way you can only mount folder from `User` folder but if I try mount another arbitary folder it mounted just as empty folder, so seems some extra work needed.